# Cannot Find Angular Build Output Folder After Build Step

Tags: github-actions

I have the following GitHub Action defined:

name: ️ Build Angular App
on:
push:
branches:
- main

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Cache node modules
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        with:
          path: ~/.npm
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-node-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-node-

      - name: Node ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}

      - name: npm ci and npm run build
        run: |
          npm ci
          npm run build
  deploy:
    name:  Deploy via FTP
    needs: [build]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name:  Get Latest Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: ⬆️ Upload Files
        uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@v4.3.4
        with:
          server: ${{ secrets.ftp_host }}
          username: ${{ secrets.ftp_user }}
          password: ${{ secrets.ftp_password }}
          local-dir: "./dist/"
          server-dir: "public_html/test/"
```

When I run this, the build step runs as expected, but in the FTP step I get the following error:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir './dist/'

So I'm guessing that I either have the wrong directory/path, or that the build output doesn't persist between the jobs. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I updated it to use the upload-artifacts action and download-artifacts action to carry the build directory between the jobs and that did the trick. Here's the full updated file:

```
name: ️ Build and Deploy Website
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    name: "️ Build Angular App"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Cache node modules
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ~/.npm
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-node-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-node-

      - name: Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16.x

      - name: npm ci and npm run build
        run: |
          npm ci
          npm run build
      - name: upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: angular-build
          path: "./dist/"
  deploy:
    name:  Deploy via FTP
    needs: [build]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: download artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: angular-build
          path: "./dist/"
      - name: ⬆️ Upload Files
        uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@v4.3.4
        with:
          server: ${{ secrets.ftp_host }}
          username: ${{ secrets.ftp_user }}
          password: ${{ secrets.ftp_password }}
          local-dir: "./dist/"
          server-dir: "public_html/home/"
```